# Stop one of Http method Online

Tags: java, jboss

I have a couple of http methods in my application which is hosted in JBoss.
And Now I am trying to find some kind of hot-way to disable one of them,like click a button in a certain of page or calling a certain of http method. What i means of 'disable it' is making any web client which intends to send get/post request to it will go to failure . Maybe we can say the web client will got a http 404 response. 
Can anybody give me some solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [JMX](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html) would be appropriate for this situation.

You can pretty easily create an MBean (Managed Bean, a component of JMX) with Managed Attributes corresponding to `boolean`'s for each of the endpoints you want to be disable-able.  Registering it is the hard part, but there are libraries out there that make working with JMX easier.  [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html) has good support for setting up and working with MBeans.

As far as a JMX client goes, I usually use VisualVM, which ships with the JDK.  From it, you can invoke methods on your MBeans at runtime, or even change their properties.

Comment: Can i just use the some http request interceptor to return 404 when i want some method disabled. and consequently I need some global thread-safety collection to maintenance 'enable' and 'disable' status of http method. So. when the interceptor receive the http request, firstly check the status in collection. then it will response relative message to client. How about this solution ? hope u give me some comments. Thanks

Comment: You could do that, but I would make the interceptor interact with an MBean like I suggested...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. need time to try both.

Comment: To my understanding . MBean is kind of proxy of endpoints . Is it correct? If I want disable a endpoint . Just change the Proxy 's state.

Comment: An MBean is a managed bean, something that can be accessed and invoked via an MBean client.